# Mongodb error: 18 getnonce failed: { ok:0.0 , errmsg: "no such cmd: getnonce" } 0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mongodb, sharding, scons

I am setting up a cluster with 2 shards, 1 config server and 1 Mongos. However, on using authentication with localhost exception I'm always facing this  error:

> 18 getnonce failed: { ok:0.0 , errmsg: "no such cmd: getnonce" } 0

On debugging the Mongodb source code I found out that `command::findCommand(commandName)` in `commands_public.cpp` is not returning "getnonce" command from authentication commands list.

I'm using Mongodb 2.4.6 and Windows 8 64bit with VS2010.

PS: this issue is only happening in Visual Studio build of Mongodb and not in scons one.

Comment: Should this have a scons tag?

Comment: well, i thought someone using scons for mongodb maybe able to answer my question more properly